# pandas apply function that returns a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a DataFrame (or Series) of `arguments`, and a function `f` which takes those arguments and returns a DataFrame.

e.g.

```
arguments = pd.DataFrame({"a": [2, 3], "b": [10, 100]})

df = pd.DataFrame({"x": [1, 0, 0], "y": [0, 1, 0], "z": [0, 0, 1]})
def f(a, b):
    return df*a*b
```

I want to get a DataFrame that stacks the DataFrames obtained from applying `f` to the arguments in each row of `arguments`:

```
     x    y    z
0   20    0    0
1    0   20    0
2    0    0   20
0  300    0    0
1    0  300    0
2    0    0  300
```

I can achieve this by explicitly constructing the result as follows...

```
pd.concat(f(a=row["a"], b=row["b"]) for _, row in arguments.iterrows())
```

...but as this is basically just an `apply` for a function that returns DataFrames, I was wondering if there's a pandas method for doing it.

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution is good. It's also very readable, which *is* important. The only thing I'd change is the way you're looping over the dataframe and passing the arguments.

Instead of user `iterrows`, you can use `to_dict('series')`, which will return a list of dicts that can be nicely expanding as keyword arguments to `f`:

```
df = pd.concat(f(**args) for args in arguments.to_dict('records'))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
     x    y    z
0   20    0    0
1    0   20    0
2    0    0   20
0  300    0    0
1    0  300    0
2    0    0  300
```